# Can't figure out why I am getting list index out of range

Tags: python, list, indexing

When I run my function, I am getting list index out of range for the underlined part of my function. When I change it to p-1 however it does not give me the error anymore except all my numbers are now negative and its not what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
def smallest_increase(pop_stats):
    
    smallest_year = 0
    
    smallest_increase = 0
    
    for p in range (len(pop_stats)):
        
        increases = pop_stats[p - 1][1]+pop_stats[p][1] 
        
        if pop_stats[p+0][1]-pop_stats[p][1]<increases and pop_stats[p][1]-pop_stats[p][1]>=0:
            
            increases = pop_stats[p+1(this is one that give error)][1] + pop_stats[p][1]
            
             
            
            print (increases)
```

```
def smallest_increase(pop_stats):
    
    smallest_year = 0
    
    smallest_increase = 0
    
    for p in range (len(pop_stats)):
        
        increases = pop_stats[p - 1][1]+pop_stats[p][1] 
        
        if pop_stats[p+0][1]-pop_stats[p][1]<increases and pop_stats[p][1]-pop_stats[p][1]>=0:
            
            increases = pop_stats[p+1][1] + pop_stats[p][1]
            
             
            
            print (increases)
```

[Image with marked line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C8kh.png)

Comment: `pop_stats[p+1]` will be out of range on the last loop iteration. Python lists are zero-indexed, so a list with p elements has a maximum valid index of p-1.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

`for p in range (len(pop_stats)):` will repeat the loop for each index of `pop_stats`. The last value of p will be the index for the end of pop_stats. This means that `[p+1]` tries to access an element off the end of the list.

Your if statement looks weird as well.

`pop_stats[p+0][1]-pop_stats[p][1]` will always be 0.
`pop_stats[p][1]-pop_stats[p][1]` will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know how you're using the function and what list you're giving it that raises the error. But I would suggest checking `p + 1 < len(pop_stats)` before attempting to access `pop_stats[p+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate p over `range(len(pop_stats))`. `len(pop_stats)` is the number of elements in that list, and the range over that number goes from zero to the number of elements in the list, but not including that number (remember that `range` is not including the upper bound of the range). So if, for instance, `pop_stats` has 100 elements in it, you get the range from zero to 99 inclusive. But since indexing starts with zero, the first element in the list will be `pop_stats[0]`, and the last element (the hundredth) will be `pop_stats[99]`. With `p+1` you get `pop_stats[100]`, which is one more than the maximum index in your list.